# res.cookie fails in Firefox (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, express

The following call

```
function attachCsrfToken(url, cookie, value) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        res.cookie(cookie, value);
        next();
    }
}

app.use(attachCsrfToken('/', 'csrfToken', (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString()));
```

fails in Firefox. I'm not able to set cookies in Firefox. When I try to debug, the server tells me that `req.cookies.csrfToken` is undefined.

In index.js, I have the following:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: Please show the full code context for the request handler where you use `res.cookie()`.  Also, if you are just doing `res.cookie(cookie, value);` with no options, then this will just be a temporary session cookie.

Comment: see above. Made some changes. @jfriend00

Comment: Do you realize that since you set no expiration in your cookie, this is not going to be a persistent cookie?

Comment: even if I do this  res.cookie(cookie, value, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)}); it still does not work

Comment: Well, there's more to the problem than you are showing us.  You can examine the response coming back to the browser in the network tab of the Chrome/Firefox debugger and see if the cookie is actually there.  Then, you can look at the actual cookies for that site in the debugger and see if browser stored it.  Then, you can look at the next request (where you are expecting the cookie to be) and see if the browser is sending it.

Comment: any other reasons it might fail?

Comment: Lots of possible reasons.  You have to do the debugging I suggested above to see which step in the process is failing - where the cookie is getting lost.  Is the client a browser?  Or, is this an API with programmatic requests?

Comment: FYI, if the request is coming from an Ajax call in the browser, then you may have to specifically enable "credentials" so that the browser will send the cookies with the Ajax call.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using axos in react.

Comment: Axios calls can pass the option `withCredentials: true` if you want to make sure that cookies are sent (on cross origin requests).